# sparql cascade in deleting individuals

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, owl, triplestore

i'm using Jena to interact with parliament triple store. The following sparql update query is to insert a new individual of a class Tenant i defined in my ontology:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org/Example#>
INSERT DATA 
{
  ex:tenant1 a ex:Tenant;
               ex:hasName "admin";
               ex:hasStatus "Enabled".
}
```

where both *hasName* and *hasStatus* are two properties defined in this ontology.
Then if i would delete *ex:tenant1* individual, is there any way in sparqle to delete in cascade all the triples that has *ex:tenant1* as subject? So, deleting only *ex:tenant1 a ex:Tenant*, i'd like to delete any references to it.
I hope i was clear in explaining my problem and thanks you in advance for your help.

Comment: Re: "i'd like to delete any references to it"  and " is there any way in SPARQL to delete in cascade all the triples that has ex:tenant1 as subject".  What happens is ex:tenant1 appears as predicate or object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Just

```
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org/Example#>
DELETE WHERE { ex:tenant1 ?p ?o }
```

This is based on the documentation:

> ### [3.1.3.3 DELETE WHERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#deleteWhere)
>
> ….
>
> #### Example 11:
>
> This example request removes all statements about anything with a
>   given name of "Fred" from the default graph:
>
> ```
> PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
>
> DELETE WHERE { ?person foaf:givenName 'Fred';
>                        ?property      ?value }
> ```

Comment: Sorry, i'm a dummy chicken :)